# My Windows Phone 7 (Nokia Lumia 900) got hijacked - How can I protect it?

Tags: security, lumia-900

Last night someone remotely controlled the browser of my Nokia Lumia 900. I was basically able to watch how the attacker clicked on different links and browsed different websites.

This happenend while I was connected to a local wifi and watched some youtube-videos on the device. Although I switched off the wifi-connection, the attack continued when the phone had a 
data connection with the mobile network. This suggests to me that the mobile network of my telephone provider was used for the attack and not the wifi-connection.

As an immediate measure, I did a factory reset of the phone, put a password to lock the screen and removed the sim-card, but I am afraid this is not enough. I am thinking about getting a new phone number.

The strange thing is that only a handful of people know my mobile number and the model, which suggests that the attacker knows me as I did not install suspicious applications or download random files with the phone.

I would like to know what I can do to secure my phone in order to prevent future attacks. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Did they have control of your browser or the whole phone? I would guess that you visited a malicious/hacked site and they were able to use JavaScript to control tabs inside your browser. If you had closed the tab(s), then I would assume the attack would have stopped.

Comment: I think they just controlled the browser. I just visited the official youtube website (m.youtube.com) to watch some videos, and the attack continued, when I changed to Google.

Comment: sounds unrealistic. Is it possible that someone played tricks on you by playing a video of a browser being clicked here and there

Comment: From a security and technical point of view, it's not possible to remotely control the phone in anyway. What you witnessed was probably only happening on the website you visited. Either that, or your screen is defective and creating fake touch-events?

Answer (score 4):

A Windows Phone can't be hijacked since all applications run in sandbox environments.

The only thing you can do to not get hijacked is to never switch to another, hijackable, platform like Android and iOS.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that you visited a malicious/hacked site and they were able to use JavaScript to control tabs inside your browser. If you had closed the tab(s), then I would assume the attack would have stopped.